# Selected read JSON by url

Tags: java, json, restfb

I want to make my code as simple as I can and don't want to download items which are not needed.

I want to select only Pages when I'm admin on facebook.

For now I use:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/?fields=id,accounts{id,perms}&summary=true&limit=100&access_token=MY_TOKEN

Results:

```
{
   "id": "101506",
   "accounts": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "6986842335",
            "perms": [
               "ADMINISTER",
               "EDIT_PROFILE",
               "CREATE_CONTENT",
               "MODERATE_CONTENT",
               "CREATE_ADS",
               "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": "1374577066121",
            "perms": [
               "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": "997587036984",
            "perms": [
               "ADMINISTER",
               "EDIT_PROFILE",
               "CREATE_CONTENT",
               "MODERATE_CONTENT",
               "CREATE_ADS",
               "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
         },
      ],
   }
}
```

Now, how to change the query to read only items with perms=ADMINISTER ?
This is what I need:

```
{
   "id": "101506",
   "accounts": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "6986842335",
            "perms": [
               "ADMINISTER",
               "EDIT_PROFILE",
               "CREATE_CONTENT",
               "MODERATE_CONTENT",
               "CREATE_ADS",
               "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
         },
         {
            "id": "997587036984",
            "perms": [
               "ADMINISTER",
               "EDIT_PROFILE",
               "CREATE_CONTENT",
               "MODERATE_CONTENT",
               "CREATE_ADS",
               "BASIC_ADMIN"
            ]
         },
      ],
   }
}
```

If I can't make the query to read what I need, maybe you know how to do this in Java to check the length of pages?
For now I have:

```
        User = facebookClient.fetchObject("v2.0/me", JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("summary", true), Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,accounts{id,perms}"), Parameter.with("limit", 100));
        Integer userFPCount = User.getJsonObject("accounts").getJsonArray("data").length();
```

But this code gives me results: 3. How to check the length of accounts.data.perms(ADMINISTER) ? I should have result: 2 in this example.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP !

Comment: Simple depends on your point of view :) You can for example use the fetchConnection method of restfb. You can even use the Version enum to define the version, atm you are using a deprecated method to generate the facebookclient. And you can use the Account type to fetch the accounts, but you should use the `me/accounts` endpoint in that case. Filter for special perms is afaik not provided by Facebook.

Comment: Thank you @Norbert . I use this query because I want download all informations what I need in 1 query. If I would use: me/accounts I couldn't fetch about me information(or I'm wrong?). Now I build 2'nd JSON object from User with only account with Admin perms. But maybe it's easier way to select only accounts with Admin permision? Could you give me some example ?

Comment: In your example code you only use the id and the accounts. So I thought you don't need any further information of the User object. Perhaps you can give an example of the data you really need. Then it should be possible to implement a better solution. And you have to filter the accounts on your side, you can perhaps add the logic in a custom restfb type but Facebook provides no filtering.